# Creating a rank/index based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, ranking

I wish to create a ranking/index in excel using multiple columns. I have tried rank and sumproduct, but I cannot achieve the desired result. I have three columns (one being a date) and would like to create the following RANK;

```
Type    WO Ref  Begin Prod  RANK
510     00513   15/11/2018  1
510     00517   16/11/2018  2
500     04678   11/12/2018  1
500     04685   19/12/2018  2
500     05836   29/12/2018  3
500     05837   29/12/2018  4
510     00523   14/12/2018  1
510     00524   15/12/2018  2
510     04797   15/12/2018  3
500     00374   04/01/2019  1
500     05090   05/01/2019  2
500     05091   06/01/2019  3
510     05830   27/01/2019  1
510     05831   27/01/2019  2
```

Ranking should be in in the following order;

1. Year/Month (from 'Begin Prod' - Column J)
2. 'Type' (Column C)
3. 'Begin Prod' (Column J)
4. 'WO Ref' (Column D)

I started using the following nested sumproduct to rank the year/month and 'Type'...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(J$2:J2,"yymm")=TEXT(J2,"yymm")),--((C$2:C2)=C2))
```

... but as soon as I add the 'Begin Prod' date the ranking changes to 1 and 2 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a quick thought:
You could introduce a new column and use the concatenate function (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)

Syntax: CONCATENATE(text1, [text2], ...).

And then sort by this column. You can hide the column if its bothering you after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

This formula (entered in M2) seems to work for the sample data, but whether it works for actual data would depend how it's sorted:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(J2:J$2,">="&EOMONTH(J2,-1)+1,J2:J$2,"<="&EOMONTH(J2,0),C2:C$2,C2)=1,1,M1+1)
```